# How do I build a dynamic MySQL INSERT statement with a flexible column count in Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, insert

I know how to do a basic insert with perl into mysql, and im not sure the tital of this question is entirely accurate.

What I am trying to do is as follows:
-I get a text file with some parameters

```
"COUNTER","DATE","TIME","ACCEL LAT","ACCEL LONG","ACCEL VERT"
```

^as an example. then I get the csv values of these.

For that you would simply do something like:

```
$query = "insert into table(counter, date, time, accel_lat, accel_long, accel_vert) 
            values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

$statement = $connection->prepare($query);

$statement->execute(MY DATA IN HERE);
```

However, the problem I have, is that the parameters I get are

- a) A subset of the ones in the mysql table (any amount from 1 to all of them)
- b) Given in a random order in the text file
- c) Not the same name as the column names in the table (I guess I would need to build a data dictionary saying which one = what)

Anyways I guess my actual question is this can I make this not static?

```
"insert into table(counter, date, time, accel_lat, accel_long, accel_vert)
```

So say my parameter file is  : date, time, counter, accel_vert

I can make the statment into

```
"insert into table(date, time, counter, accel_vert)
```

Like to define my inset statment based on what I read from the text file (like how we use ? because we dont know the values yet, I need a way to use ? for the columns since I won't know them yet).

Is this possible? Sorry if I am unclear, can explain if you ask.

Comment: Use string interpolation: `my $val="Hello"; my $query="values ($val)"` ? See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs)

Comment: @HåkonHægland The OP is already using placeholders, there's absolutely nothing to be gained from switching to interpolation.

Comment: @HåkonHægland isnt that just for the values though...? not for the table columns? is there a way to do that for NOT the values, but instead for the inset into table (this part) ?

Comment: If you know the column *names*, order doesn't matter: `INSERT INTO table (foo, bar) VALUES ('baz', 'qux')` is the same as `INSERT INTO table (bar, foo) VALUES ('qux', 'baz')`. And since you're listing the columns, both of these will work even if the table has more columns than just `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot which is where problem a) also comes in. what if I do foo,bar. and I only have values for foo in this document or of foo,bar,raa, ect. As mentioned I will not know which columns I will be inserting into. I dont know how to build an insert statement to accommodate that fact.

Comment: If you only have a value for column `foo`, then do `INSERT INTO table (foo) VALUES ('bar')`. Default values will be used for any columns you don't specify.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes I know that. and that works for that ONE case. my parameter list is anywhere from 1 -1057 paramaters. I cant do 100trillion if statements going (if its just foo do this) (if its foo + bar do this insert) (if its just bar do this insert) ect ect ect. The whole point is it needs to be a dynamic insert statment, since there are to many possibilities to have if statements for them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to build your query dynamically. It's perfectly fine to use variable interpolation for the column names. You should just not use those directly from the CSV columns. Your idea of a dictionary is spot-on.

I've written up a simple example. The trick is to just have the right number of placeholders `?` in your SQL. The `x` [repetition operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) is useful for that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);

# csv => mysql
my %column_mapping = (
    qux => 'Qux',
    foo => 'Foo',
    bar => 'Bar',
    baz => 'Baz',
);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();

# get the headline
my $headers = $csv->getline( \*DATA );

# build the INSERT query based on those column headers
my $sql = sprintf 'INSERT INTO tablename ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )',
    join( ',', map { $column_mapping{$_} } @$headers ),
    join( ',', ('?') x scalar @$headers );   # note the list around the '?'

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA ) ) {
    $sth->execute( @$row ) or die $dbh->errstr;
}

__DATA__
foo,bar,baz
1,2,3
5,5,5
```

In my example, `$sql` has this value:

```
INSERT INTO tablename ( Foo,Bar,Baz ) VALUES ( ?,?,? )
```

---

See also:

- [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV)

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding I needed it dynamic:D Just for the record its not actually a csv its an xml but the important data in it is sort of csv like. But I can defintly modify this to what I need I think. Huge thanks

Comment: @Lain I think your requirement was pretty clear, and the question is well-written. I've used this kind of thing for importing huge CSV files where I would also create the tables on the fly as part of the analysis of a new project where simply using a mysql tool to read CSV was not working due to the size or the non-conformity of the CSV file.

Comment: I assume this sort of thing works fine if its just a text file and not a csv file also? only differences are the lines that have csv in them?

Comment: @lain Doesn't matter where your data comes from. If you would have this in XML you would just use a parser to build a data structure. If it's JSON you can just convert that to a perl data structure and iterate. And a text file is essentially a CSV file with one column. It's all a matter of definition. CSV is quite flexible. In Germany it's common to have `;` as a sep_char, but we still call it _comma_ separated value and not _SSV_. Noone stops you from using a ` ` or a `\0` or whatever you want as the separator. Whatever suits your need. You can use `\n` also and have one column per 'line'. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I am actually a beginner at perl (started learning yesterday for work lol) for the data maping part. where you have something like this foo => 'Foo'  what happenes if it is fo o instead of foo (like 2 words) can I do "two words" => 'Two_Words' noticed you didnt have quotes before, wasnt sure if this breaks it or not.

Comment: @Lain The `=>` is called the fat comma. It behaves like a regular `,` with the benefit of adding quotes around the left hand side. That only works for one word. So if your left side (usually that's a _key_) is more than one, you need to quote it yourself. Take a look at the ressources linked in the Perl tag wiki here on SO, those are really good. Don't just google tutorials. Don't trust any teaching ressource that does not have `use strict` and `use warnings`. And come back and ask new questions if you need help.